# Scanning to PDF/A on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, software-rec, scanner

[PDF/A](http://www.pdfa.org/doku.php?id=artikel:en:pdfa_for_scanned_documents) is one of the best formats to archive my documents.

What Linux software would allow me to scan documents to PDF/A ?

A PNG→PDF/A or TIFF→PDF/A tool would be fine too.

Comment: OpenOffice seems able to convert office documents to PDF/A, but not really conveninent for images: http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/generating-pdfa-for-long-term-archiving.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If document images (no ocr) is acceptable, then use xsane to scan to postscript files and use ghostscript to concatenate the postscript files. Convert the resulting .ps to PDF/A using ghostscript, using [these instructions](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517025748/http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA)).

Comment: Great :-D I will scan to postscript with SANE and then convert to PDF/A using the -dPDFA option of ghostscript. I don't need OCR indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The program called 'gscan2pdf' scans directly to pdf, and if your scanner has a document feeder, it will automatically combine the multiple pages into a single pdf file. It can also run ocr software on each page of the scans, and perform alignment/corrections when needed.

In ubuntu, you can find it under 'Applications->Graphics'. If it's not there, then you can install it with 'System->Administration->Synaptic Package Manager', with a quick search for 'gscan2pdf'.

Comment: I was asking for PDF/A. I already have gscan2pdf, it can't do PDF/A

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSane, you select multipage scan and you'll get a option to save to PDF.

Comment: I was asking for PDF/A specifically. XSane does not do PDF/A